# Knex / ObjectionJs whereJsonSupersetOf with object containing an array

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, objection.js

I use knex and objection.js with a postgresQL database.
I updated knex from version 0.19.5 to 1.0.3 and part of one of my query stopped working.
One of my table has a 'metadata' column, which is jsonb. The metadata object can contain a keyword property, which is an array of strings. I want to query for the presence of a word in that array.

Before:

```
   .where('Source.name', 'ilike', `%${search}%`)
   .orWhere('Attribution.normalizedName', 'ilike', `%${search}%`)
   .orWhere('Source.abstract', 'ilike', `%${search}%`)
   .orWhere('Source.description', 'ilike', `%${search}%`)
   .orWhereJsonSupersetOf('Source.metadata:keywords', [search])
```

This was working before I upgraded, but now I get an error saying that 'column Source.metadata:keywords does not exist'

I didn't see anything in the knex changelog that explained a breaking change there.
(this was done with objection.js version 2.1.3)

Comment: can you provide a sample of json data in that column?

Comment: Source.metadata would look like:
{
"publicationYear": 1980,
"isbn": "12345...",
"keywords": ["word1", "word2"]
}
It can contain other properties as well, but the keywords array is where I am having a problem.